# Redux-Saga: Change url after API call complete

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

In My saga, I want to change the url after API call (logging, doesn't matter the api success or fail)

My logic is like below

```
function* logSaga(action) {
  yield call(logAPI, action.payload)
  yield put(push('some_url'))
}

function* watchLogSaga() {
  yield takeLatest('LOG_ACTION_TYPE', logSaga)
}
```

However, because I'm changing the url, the api call will always get canceled . Is there any way I can make the API call while changing URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can with change `takeLastest` to `takeEvery`

```
function* watchLogSaga() {
  yield takeEvery('LOG_ACTION_TYPE', logSaga)
}
```